# How to split a string in words that is tab separted in Python

Tags: python

I have a list of lines where words in each line are separated by tab characters as follows:

```
 ajay   vijay   0.6
 vijay  ajay    0.7
 ravi   vijay   0.8
 swati  swapnesh    0.4
```

Then how I can extract words from each of the line in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Learn `split` function : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm

So if your string is "A    B     C",

```
str = "A    B     c"
li = list(str.split("\t"))
```

`\t` is representing `tabs`

Comment: Indexes start from 0 ; Maybe common sense, just thought it would be good to know.

Answer (score 0):

`your_string.split("\t")` should return you a list of words.